# Unity3d Can't use equip prefab.

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Trying to play around with unity so I made a simple player controller, and a weapon controller. 
I drag my Weapon Controller onto my player, and I try to assign a Prefab as the starting Gun, but for some reason it doesn't let me do it. I can't drag the Prefab to the startingGun in my script.

My weapon controller looks like this:

```
namespace Assets.Scripts.Weapon
{
    public class WeaponController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Transform WeaponHold;
        public Gun startingGun;
        private Gun EquippedGun;

        void Start()
        {
            if (startingGun != null)
            {
                EquipWeapon(startingGun);   
            }   
        }

        public void EquipWeapon(Gun gunToEquip)
        {
            if (gunToEquip != null)
                Destroy(EquippedGun.gameObject);

            EquippedGun = Instantiate(gunToEquip, WeaponHold.position, WeaponHold.rotation) as Gun;
            if (EquippedGun != null)
                EquippedGun.transform.parent = WeaponHold;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you're trying to assign a prefab to a variable with the type GameObject - instead you need to use the following code then you should be able to add the prefab in the inspector:

```
public Object startingGun;
```

Comment: I have tried that, still dosen't work. I drag drag my prefab onto it. Nor if I use the little button to select a prefab I can't choose it here either

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of your scene and inspector of the object the script is attached to?

Comment: Updated my answer - test to see if that solves your problem

Comment: No, that's the first thing i tested as well.

Comment: That's weird - i used that code and managed to get a prefab into my code: another technique you could try is Resource.Load(path) where path is the path to your prefab

Comment: How ever, even though it is a gun I should have access to a sign a prefab to it.

Comment: you are not dragging it from the scene  right , you are draging it from project tab?